# Text do not show up with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added the following navbar with the new bootstrap 4 version. but it doesn't show anything below the nav bar as well. The text inserted after the nav, also it doesn't take the width and height properties if an external css file is used to give css to the image inserted below. Any idea why this is happening??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Forestpin</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/home.css"/>
  
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="assets/images/logofpin.png" alt="Forestpin" width="70" height="30">
  </a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Products
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Risk Engine</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Analytics</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Insights</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
vdfnfhmjhngsdhfjfnd
fdbnmjnfbdfgn
sample text

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried changing the position of the script, but still the text is not shown

Comment: text is hiding behind the fixed nav bar.! not sure why!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nav tag `fixed-top` class causes the issue. You are suppose to use `navbar-fixed-top` for fixed navbar. Check below snippet for reference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Forestpin</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/home.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light navbar-fixed-top bg-faded">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="assets/images/logofpin.png" alt="Forestpin" width="70" height="30">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Products
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Risk Engine</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Analytics</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Insights</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  vdfnfhmjhngsdhfjfnd fdbnmjnfbdfgn sample text
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/ yes it worked... this link mentions what i have used. Used the code from this documentation.

Comment: am not sure why this kind of issues are coming then!

Comment: @SameeraVithanage — It's an **alpha**, it is expected to be buggy (and not ready for production use). That's probably an error in the documentation.